# Forwarding http to https in AWS Load Balancers

Tags: amazon-elb

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk, and I installed my SSL certificate in my EB load balancer. Every time the server is not healthy, the load balancer delete the instance and creates a new one, which means I'm gonna lose my redirection codes and SSL set up that I installed inside the instance.

That's why I installed my SSL on the load balancer. However, how can I redirect HTTP to HTTPS on the load balancer?

I used to redirect by putting the below codes inside the instance, but if I keep doing this way, when the load balancer removes an unhealthy instance, I'm gonna lose my redirection from HTTP to HTTPS.

What should I do?

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  ServerName (domain).com
  ServerAlias www.(domain).com
  RedirectPermanent / https://www.(domain).com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE**

Here's my listeners on Load Balancers in EC2

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a load balancer in AWS, the common use case is to install the SSL certificate on the load balancer. This is commonly called SSL offloading or Layer 7 load balancing. Traffic from the load balancer to the EC2 instance is not encrypted and typically over port 80 (sometimes 8080) (HTTP). Traffic from the client to your load balancer is defined by the listeners that you created.

Layer 4 load balancing uses TCP to talk to your EC2 instance and you install the SSL certificate on your web server. Your web server then knows what port the client is connecting on and the following DOES NOT APPLY.

Your code running your website needs to check if the client connected to the load balancer using HTTPS. If true, don't redirect the client. If the client connected to the load balancer using HTTP, then redirect the client.

The following PHP code shows how to read the Load Balancer headers that are sent to your EC2 instance to determine if the client connected over HTTPS. If you are not using a language such as PHP or Nodes.js, you can also create Apache configurations that know how to read the correct headers (example at the bottom).

```
function require_ssl()
{
        global $config_require_ssl;

        if ($config_require_ssl == FALSE)
        {
                return;
        }

        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']))
        {
                if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
                {
                       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
                }
        }

        if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
        {
                header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

                exit();
        }
}
```

This is the code for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
    …
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: FYI, I'm using Python as a backend language. The point of my question is "What if the Apache server is deleted?" The load balancer delete an EC2 instance. That's why I'm trying to avoid to set up redirection codes inside Apache server. It's the same thing that I wanna install SSL on the load balancer, NOT inside Apache server because if the EC2 instance is deleted, I'm gonna lose my SSL.

Comment: Port the PHP to Python or use the Apache configuration. You are missing one component in your design. Configure your server exactly as your need it. Then create an AMI. Specify that AMI in your configuration that launches EC2 instances. There are also other methods such as specifying User Data when launching an instance that configures a new instance. My preferred language is Python, so I should port my PHP to Python but I like PHP for websites.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up the application that you've got running in Elastic Beanstalk to configure Http to Https redirection.

Then when setting up the Load Balancer through Elastic Beanstalk create 2 listeners one for port 80 and one for 433, which both forward on.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html

Comment: I've already set up the application. Is there a forwarding setup under Configuration in Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: That's what I've already done. To make sure, I updated my post with a picture of my listeners in the load balancer. Can you check that out if I set up correctly?

Comment: That looks correct, do the security groups have the correct ports open?

Comment: Oh I see you're forwarding both 443 and 80 to 80 on that server, you need to forward traffic from 443 to the 443 port on that machine. Alternatively use 81 to make it less confusing as you're not using https between load balancer and EC2 instance

Comment: I tried that one listener for 80 to 80 and another listener for 443 to 443. Unfortunately, that still doesn't redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can offload the SSL traffic at the Application Load Balancer(ALB) and the communication between ALB and you can configure the redirection from http to https using EC2 web server configuration.

You are right that if there no running servers the redirection won't work. Infact the response will be a different error where the resource is not accessible. If you configure the autoscaling and load balancing with more than one instance, for most of the cases at least one healthy instance should be able to do the redirection.